# Qt: "No such signal" error

Tags: c++, qt

I have a simple code; here I've two buttons, I press the first one and it shows a MsgBox. Then I press the "Okay", and it *should* call a connected action written in a second button, but it doesn't. Instead I get an error:

```
Object::connect: No such signal QMessageBox::buttonClicked(QMessageBox::Ok)
Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'OpenFile_Bttn')
```

The code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_OpenFile_Bttn_clicked(){
    QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open file"), "", tr(""));//Open a dialog "OpenFile"
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText("Push button to choose a file");
    //Connect clicking button in MsgBox to an action in OpenFile_Bttn button
    QWidget::connect(&msgBox,SIGNAL(buttonClicked(QMessageBox::Ok)),
            ui->OpenFile_Bttn, SLOT(on_OpenFile_Bttn_clicked()));
    msgBox.exec();//Show MsgBox
}
```

Also I found an interesting thing, that the error message appears when a MsgBox popup, but not when I click the button "Ok" inside the MsgBox.

Comment: I'm voting to close, because your question is a typographical error - `SIGNAL(msgBox.buttonClicked(QMessageBox::Ok))` - you shouldn't add the member variable, it should be `SIGNAL(buttonClicked(QMessageBox::Ok))` instead. In the future, use the intellisense (if you're in Qt Creator), it will prevent silly errors like that. Even the error text - `No such signal QMessageBox::msgBox.buttonClicked` should have alerted you, notice QMessageBox:: **msgBox** .buttonClicked.

Comment: Same as sashoalm. Also, your `SLOT` should be `on_OpenFile_Bttn_clicked()` rather than `ui->OpenFile_Bttn->on_OpenFile_Bttn_clicked()`. Use Qt creator can prevent this kind of errors.

Comment: @sashoalm thank you, I changed the code, but the error remains the same. I'll fix code in topic also...

Comment: @Tay2510 thank you too, I fixed it, but the error remains anyway.

Comment: Is the error still the same?  You might want to edit the current error in as well.

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes, the error the same, there's no need to edit it.

Comment: @RetiredNinja though the scope in error changed, yes, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for signals here, exec returns the button clicked.

```
void MainWindow::on_OpenFile_Bttn_clicked(){
    QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open file"), "", tr(""));//Open a dialog "OpenFile"
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setText("Push button to choose a file");
    //Connect clicking button in MsgBox to an action in OpenFile_Bttn button
    if(msgBox.exec() == QMessageBox::Ok)
    {
      on_OpenFile_Bttn_clicked();
    }
}
```

If you want to use custom buttons you can still call `msgBox.buttonClicked()` after exec to find out which button was clicked.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't even knew about this function!

Answer (score 2):

If you do this instead you get a compiler error, that way you can see something is wrong at compile instead of runtime error

```
QObject::connect(msgBox, &QMessageBox::buttonClicked, ui->OpenFile_Bttn, &QPushButton::clicked);
```

out of interest the above code is untested and probably wont compile but basicallt just do sender, signal, reciever, slot but use their class object to select signal and slots like shown above and then you will get an easier to spot compile error that tells you what could be wrong